# Why does this implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm work in O(n^2)?

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra

Here is the code I use for implementing Dijkstra's algorithm. Consider a graph with *n* vertices and *m* edges. Shouldn't it run in O(*n*^2 *m*) ? Someone may say that there are *n* vertices and each edge gets processed once, therefore it is O(*n* *m*). But the while loop can run at most *n* times, the 1st for loop at most *n* times and the second for loop at most *m* times. Therefore, this should be an O(*n^2* *m*) implementation.

Here X is a vector, head[] and shortest[] are arrays.

```
X.push_back(1);
head[1] = true;

while(X.size()!=MAX) {
    min = INT_MAX;

    for(j=0;j<X.size();j++) {
        node = X[j];

        for(k=0;k<graph[node].size();k++) {
            v = graph[node][k];

            if(head[v]==true)
                continue;

            if(min>(weight[node][k]+shortest[node])) { 
                pos = v;
                min = weight[node][k]+shortest[node];
            }
       }
  }

  shortest[pos] = min;
  head[pos] = true;

  X.push_back(pos);
}
```

Comment: [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is supposed to be `O(m + n log n)`, so even `O(n^2)` is more than is required.

Comment: @Rufflewind since `m = O(n^2)`, `O(n^2)` is correct (although rougher).

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo In the worst case scenario (a complete graph, `m = n`, so it would be `O(n^3)`.  (Assuming by `m` the OP refers to edges per vertex.)

Comment: @Rufflewind yeah, I know. I was referring to the formula in your comment, not to the one in the question.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: `O(n log n)` is very different from `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Rufflewind but `O(m + n log n)` is `O(n² + n log n)`, which is `O(n²)`...

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Ah, yes I see what you mean!  I mixed up the interpretations of the variable `m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a similar query about Time complexity, which was cleared by JanHudec ([Why does this algorithm work in O(n m)?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271230/why-does-this-algorithm-work-in-on-m/271233#271233)), I now have an answer to my problem.

The time complexity should be seen from the iterations of the innermost loop. *k* gets incremented at most *m* times in every iteration of the while loop. 
Hence, there is an O(*n* *m*) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I'm not well-versed in graph algorithms but I don't think your code implements Dijkstra's algorithm correctly.  Your code as it stands will check vertices more than once, which is not what a correct implementation should do.

In Dijkstra's algorithm, one keeps track of a set of *unvisited vertices* so as to avoid re-checking vertices that have already been checked.  Your code keeps track of a set of *visited vertices*, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This might be the case, but I still want to find out what the complexity of the algorithm with this implementation is.

Comment: @DhruvMullick: your code is `O(m n^2)` as you said.